# How to set up the environment for react native?

Tags: react-native

I am having trouble getting started with react native. I used the `sudo npm i -g react-native-cli` and it said "changed 85 packages, and audited 86 packages in 8s

40 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities"

and then when I enter `react-native init project`

it says no such command found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this url.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Thank you.
Regards.

Comment: should i use the expo one or the other?

Comment: It depends on you. if you want full customize, you need to choose react-native-cli else expo.